# Error when upload file size > 5MB in php?

Tags: php

I had uploaded file size >5MB and config in `php.ini`

[image: php.ini]

But when upload file is result `error File Error size ini`, how to config it!

Comment: What is the value for "post_max_size"?

Comment: After changing the values don't forget to restart the services ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is another configuration entry that affects this behavior: `post_max_size`

Answer (score 3):

There are, in fact, three additional configuration entries you should worry about in this case.

> Two PHP configuration options control the maximum upload size: **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size**. Both can be set to, say, “10M” for 10 megabyte file sizes.
>
> However, you also need to consider the time it takes to complete an upload. PHP scripts normally time-out after 30 seconds, but a 10MB file would take at least 3 minutes to upload on a healthy broadband connection (remember that upload speeds are typically five times slower than download speeds). In addition, manipulating or saving an uploaded image may also cause script time-outs. We therefore need to set PHP’s **max_input_time** and **max_execution_time** to something like 300 (5 minutes specified in seconds).

Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/