# Uploading and storing files using php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am struggling to get file upload working. I tried my own code, which didn't work (no surprise, I am working with file upload for the first time) but neither did other codes I tried like [this one](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) or [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). 
I need to upload an image (or even better, more images at once). I don't even need something complicated, I only need to upload jpeg images through form and save them. 
I have my server on local network Raspberry Pi (LAMP). 
Is there some specific setting I need? Any ideas why none of these codes work for me?
//Mostly solved, more questions below

```
$path= "images/" . $_FILES['ufile']['name'];
if($ufile !=none){
if(copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path)){
    echo "Successful<br/>"; 
    echo "File Name :".$_FILES['ufile']['name']."<br/>"; 
    echo "File Size :".$_FILES['ufile']['size']."<br/>"; 
    echo "File Type :".$_FILES['ufile']['type']."<br/>"; 
    echo "<img src=\"" . $path . "\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
    }
else{
echo "Error";
}
}
```

As I said, it works for small files. I belive the limit is around 2MB. Any ideas on how to make it unlimited (or at least less limited)?

```
; max_input_time
;   Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
;   Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
;   Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
```

Comment: What were the errors you were getting and how didn't the codes you tried work?

Comment: What didn't work, specifically? Also, try to choose a better site for reference. The [PHP Manual](http://php.net) works best!

Comment: It would be best to share the code that you have already tried and then we can help you to improve it and get it working.

Comment: There are two links in the end of second line to codes I tried. Both died on first if statement. Only thing I changed was url in <form> tag. I tried several images, without change.

Comment: I copied one of the codes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this tutorial](http://www.phpeasystep.com/php-cate.php?category=file-upload), choose the type you want and it is well explained..

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Going to try it now.

Comment: Glad I could help, please tick the answer. :)

Comment: I have to try it first ;)

Comment: So, it worked in the end. I had to change the $HTTP_POST_FILES to $_FILES. I can upload small pictures, but it doesn't work with larger images. I read somwhere it might be because of the php.ini file, which restricts the file size. Am I right?

Comment: Oh yeah, you must have atleast 775 as the file permission.

Comment: Two possibilities, 1) you have a limit in the script, in the tutorial they have added a limit,  check the `$limit_size`..2) check `post_max_size` value in php.in

Comment: So I changed the post_max_size to ulimited and it didn'y work. I copied my current code to my first post.

Comment: Sorry my bad, check for `upload_max_filesize`,`post_max_size`,`max_input_time` in php.ini and see if it suits your needs..

Comment: So, `upload_max_filesize` set to 0 (comment said it menas unlimited), `post_max_siz`e as well and `max_input_time` was set to default -1 (which should mean unlimited as well). Btw it seems like it's commented out is it matters (copied to original post). And nothing has changed, I still can't upload larger files.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500382/error-when-upload-file-size-5mb-in-php and also what is the value of `$limit_size` or if you can post the complete php code which you have edited..

Comment: I've got it! I should stop solving such a problems in the middle of the night. After the second modification of php.ini I forget to restart server... Thank you for your help!